# Converting MySQL datetime to ElasticSearch strict_date_optional_time

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

While trying to insert MySQL to ElasticSearch, I'm getting the following error: `mapper_parsing_exception: failed to parse [updated_time]`

The `updated_time` I'm trying to push is `2017-01-23 17:41:27`

The mapping is defined as:

```
"updated_time": {
     "type": "date",
     "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
 }
```

Oddly, when sending such a datetime from Logstash, ElasticSearch is ok with it. But when sending from the official PHP library it fails on this.

It looks like a pretty strict datetime object that comes directly from MySQL. Do I need to convert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datetime coming from MySQL is not ISO8601 compliant, which is required from `strict_date_optional_time`.

You can amend your mapping like this in order to accept another date format

```
PUT your_index/_mapping/your_type?update_all_types=true
{ 
   "properties" : {
      "updated_time": {
         "type": "date",
         "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can I change this mapping for a index full with data?

Comment: Yes, you may try since you're not changing the field type

Comment: Might it cause problems when I'll later on try to filter by this field? (I'll have dates in more than one format)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Adding a new pattern won't have any effect on existing indexed data. You're only telling ES to also start accepting dates with the new format, that's all

Comment: Mapping update is failing on this: `Mapper for [updated_time] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [updated_time] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [format] across all types.]`

Comment: Ok, you have other types as well, then add `?update_all_types=true` to your URL

Comment: I actually didn't intend to have other type, accidentally added a 'updated_time' type it appears. I can just `DELETE my_index/updated_time` to clean that up, right?

Comment: I don't get you... did it work out? You need to make sure to replace `your_index`  and `your_type` with your real index and type names.

Comment: Yep, worked out. Just somehow had a side effect of adding another type to the index, `         "updated_time": {
            "properties": {
               "updated_time": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
               }
            }
         }`

Comment: See my answer above and copy paste it exactly, I didn't have `updated_time` as type name, only a field name. So yes, `DELETE my_index/updated_time` would work

Comment: I think it was the query you had before (with my wrong inputs?) the edit that also created /myindex/updated_time as a type.

Comment: The delete fails on `no handler found`

Comment: My bad, actually you cannot delete a mapping type once created. let it be it won't hurt. Or recreate your index from scratch